No module named 'selenium', despite using the correct Python interpreter
I want to preface this by saying that I do know that there are already many other posts from people experiencing the same issue, but I have tried them all and have not been able to find a solution. So here is a detailed description of my issue:
I am currently trying to build a web scrapper using selenium but I am running into this following error:
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

The common solutions that I have seen online are to:

Restart IDE
Make sure selenium is installed in the correct location
Make sure you have selected the correct interpreter
Reinstall selenium

I have made sure to do all of these steps but still no luck.
For reference, the path to my interpreter is:
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.9
And when I run pip show selenium, this is the output:
Name: selenium
Version: 4.23.1
Summary: Official Python bindings for Selenium WebDriver
Home-page: https://www.selenium.dev
Author: 
Author-email: 
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: certifi, trio, trio-websocket, typing_extensions, urllib3, websocket-client
Required-by: 

I also am not getting any sort of warnings or errors in my editor (VSCode) related to imports either.
I'm not sure if I am missing something extremely obvious but it does seem like this should be working. If anyone needs more information, I can provide.

When you run pip,  the module shows up. But how are you starting your script? When you print sys.executable, does the Python executable match the one that goes with your pip?
